# Array is printing more numbers than intended?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm supposed to create and initialize a 100-element array, then make the 7th element the number "7", and finally print the array, starting a new line every 20 elements. I've been trying to figure this out for a long time and I can't.

My code right now is:

```
public class Array {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int [] array = new int[100];  

        for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
            if (array[a] == 6) {
                array[a]=7;
                array[a] = a + 1;
            }
            printArray(array);
        }
    }

    public static void printArray(int[] array){
        for (int a=0; a < array.length; a++) {
            System.out.print(" " + array[a]);
            if ((a - 1) % 20 == 0) {
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this my output is a lot of zeros, far more than 100. They are separated every 20 characters as intended, but the seventh element is not 7. I think it has to do with the association between int "a" and my array, but I can't figure it out. I know the solution must be simple but I just cannot see it. Thank you all!

Comment: Your code and the description of the wanted behavior do not make sense what so ever. `if (array[a] == 6) {
                array[a]=7;
    array[a] = a + 1; }` What is this?

Comment: what are you initializing the array with

Comment: @Gendarme If the array is in the 7th position (a==6), set that element to 7, and then continue to the next one. That's what I intended.

Comment: It is not checking if `a == 6`. And *"continue to next one"* is what is making this code super weird. You are inside a loop; it **will** continue, there is no need for you to do anything. Just delete that last line.

Answer (score 1):

Proper indentation of your code, in particular the `main` method, reveals what is going on.  You are calling `printArray` from within the `for` loop, so you are printing the array contents 100 times.

```
    for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
        if (array[a] == 6) {
            array[a]=7;
            array[a] = a + 1;
        }
        printArray(array);
    }
```

Move the call to `printArray` after the `}` ending brace for the `for` loop.

Now you'll get 100 `0`s.

Also, I think you meant to have `array[a] = a + 1;` executed if the index was not `6`, e.g.

```
if (array[a] == 6) {
    array[a] = 7;
} else {
    array[a] = a + 1;
}
```

Additionally, you will want to print a newline after 20 numbers, e.g. after indexes `19`, `39`, etc., so add `1` to `a` before calculating the remainder, instead of subtracting `1`, so that `19 + 1 = 20`, whose remainder is `0`.

Comment: i think he intended to set a 7 at index 6. so...
if (a == 6) {
    array[a] = 7;
} else {
    array[a] = a + 1;
}

Comment: im pretty sure that he wanted to change the 7th element to the value of 7 so he needed to ask this:
if (a == 6)

Comment: I think the else has to be removed in total together with `array[a] = a + 1;`. I think he is seeing that line as `continue;`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong.  However, to answer your question, you are printing the array 100 times since printArray is inside your first loop.

Answer (score 0):

You misplaced an end parenthesis in your main method. The properly formatted method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int [] array = new int[100];  

    for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++) {
        if (array[a] == 6) {
                array[a]=7;
        }
        array[a] = a + 1;
    }

    printArray(array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is organized very badly so it's very easy for u to miss what went where. You have 2 major mistakes, first of all you called `printArray()`
Inside your for loop and therefore printed it 100 times.
Second, you kept checking if the value inside the array in index `a` is 6.
You need to check if `a` is 6 since it is your index like this:

```
if(a == 6)
    array[a] = 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ran your code, and there are a few places that can be corrected.

As for your problem of the many things being printed, that's because you've placed your printarray() inside the for loop, so it's printing the array 100 times.

As for printing it out, i find this code to be more concise:

```
public static void printArray(int[] array){
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        counter++;
        if(counter == 20){
            counter = 0;
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I'm not really sure why you're using a for loop to just change the 7th element. You could  use this:

```
array[6] = 7;
```

I'm not really sure what you're doing in the for loop.

I hope this helped! Good luck!